# Does packet sniffing reduces internet speed?

Tags: tcpdump, sniffer

I'm using [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org) command tool to sniff packets. However, I worry about my internet speed to be reduced. Does a packet sniffer reduce it? If yes or no, why?

If it does, is there any way to fix this problem? Can I ignore its effect on internet speed (i.e. is its effect negligible)?

Thanks!

Comment: lets say you are on a 100 MBPS network, if you are capturing in amounts of 1000s of MBs, then you will have to wait for ~10 extra seconds. but usually you wont capture more than a few MBs so it'll be negligible according to your net speed

Comment: @AkashGupta Then what if the network sniffer stay turned on and capture all packet of every second of every day? For instance, if you want to measure the size of data used by every user?

Comment: Its as simple as this, whatever data target device uses, you will also use (download) so if the data is massive, network may slow down

Comment: @AkashGupta No; I mean, for example, when you turn your WiFi hotstop, to measure the size of data which is transferring on wlan0 interface, separated by connected devices (i.e. more than 1 device) using their MAC address.

Answer (score 5):

No, sniffing your network does not slow it down.  However, the system on which the sniffer is running may run slower since MAC filtering has been turned off on the NIC and all packets are forwarded to the OS.  This will not generate errors since the packets are not addressed to the system, but it still has to look at them.

Additionally, if you are configuring a span or mirror on your switch in order to sniff, this can slow your switch down a bit, but the impact is extremely unlikely to be noticeable..  On the order of microseconds of potential delay.

Comment: Even if you sniff packets with buffering?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't matter if they are buffered.  With MAC filtering disabled, those frames are all forwarded to the network stack.

Comment: How about MAC filtering enabled? How about adding -e option to tcpdump command to show MAC addresses?

Comment: The -e option only shows them, it doesn't do anything about the filtering.  If you are running a promiscuous sniffer, you have hardware MAC filtering disabled.

Comment: Asking a question after a while; however, is denying some devices to use my traffic by their MAC addresses means MAC filtering? Something like using [tc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/intro.html) command (Traffic Control)?

Comment: No, @MAChitgarha, that's not what I'm talking about.  I'm referring to the network card only forwarding broadcasts, subscribed multicast channels, and its own address unless you turn off filtering.